# Error in signal plot with matlab (error matrix dimensions must agree)

Tags: matlab

I want to take the plot of a signal with the mathematical function:

x(t)=0.001t^3exp(-0.1t)

I try this code and i take the error below:

```
>> t=[0:100];
>> x(t)=0.001*t.^3*exp(-0.1*t)
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

I dont know how to fix this error, after that i will use "stem(Y)" to take the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using vector multiplication when you should use element-wise multiplication:

```
>> x(t)=0.001*t.^3*exp(-0.1*t) % ERROR
```

vs.

```
>> x(t)=0.001*t.^3.*exp(-0.1*t) % OK
                  ^
                  difference
```